# Spring Scheduler not being executed if its component class is not injected

Tags: spring, kotlin

Suddenly the scheduler stopped working, and it only works TriggerScheduler is injected into another component.

If it is not injected it doesn't even appear on IntelliJ Endpoints -> Beans -> Application, so the triggers aren't executed because i guess the bean is not instantiated. Neither in that case the ProjectFormTriggerExecutor, ProjectTriggerExecutor, DistrictTriggerExecutor and AreaMonitoringFragmentTriggerExecutor are instantiated.

The purpose of the bean is to asyncronously trigger PostgreSQL triggers, there is another trigger which just sets markedForUpdate = true when conditions are met.

Everything works fine when i dummy inject it into another Component.

Why is this happening? Is there some spring configuration somebody of my team changed to not instantiate uninjected beans or something?

```
@file:Suppress("JpaQlInspection")

package com.gilbertjolly.ulsi.mgmt.application

import com.gilbertjolly.lib.crud.CrudEntity
import com.gilbertjolly.lib.crud.RecalculationPeriod
import com.gilbertjolly.lib.crud.request_util.newTransaction
import com.gilbertjolly.ulsi.mgmt.feature.model.country.District
import com.gilbertjolly.ulsi.mgmt.feature.model.metrics.entities.AreaMonitoringFragment
import com.gilbertjolly.ulsi.mgmt.feature.model.monitoring.forms.ProjectForm
import com.gilbertjolly.ulsi.mgmt.feature.model.org.Project
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager
import java.time.Instant
import java.util.logging.Logger
import javax.persistence.EntityManager
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

@Component
abstract class ScheduledTriggerExecutor {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var txManager: PlatformTransactionManager

    @Autowired
    lateinit var entityManager: EntityManager

    val recalculationPeriod: RecalculationPeriod get() = RecalculationPeriod.EVERY_MINUTE

    val logger = Logger.getLogger("TriggerRecalculationLog")!!

    abstract val entityClass: KClass<out CrudEntity>

    fun executeTrigger() {
        val startMilliseconds = Instant.now().toEpochMilli()

        txManager.newTransaction {
            entityManager.createQuery("UPDATE ${entityClass.simpleName} SET markedForUpdate = FALSE WHERE markedForUpdate = TRUE")
                    .executeUpdate()
        }

        val triggerExecutionMilliseconds = Instant.now().minusMillis(startMilliseconds).toEpochMilli()

        if (triggerExecutionMilliseconds > 5000) logger.warning("Trigger execution of ${entityClass.simpleName} took ${triggerExecutionMilliseconds / 1000.0f}")
    }

}

@Component
class TriggerScheduler(val env: Environment,
                       val txManager: PlatformTransactionManager,
                       val scheduledTriggerExecutors: List<ScheduledTriggerExecutor>) {

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 1 1 * * ?")
    fun everyNightAt101() {
        performRecalculation(RecalculationPeriod.AT_NIGHT)
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 1 * * * ?")
    fun everyHour() {
        performRecalculation(RecalculationPeriod.HOURLY)
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/30 * * * ?")
    fun every30Minutes() {
        performRecalculation(RecalculationPeriod.EVERY_HALF_AN_HOUR)
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/2 * * * ?")
    fun every2Minutes() {
        performRecalculation(RecalculationPeriod.EVERY_TWO_MINUTES)
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * * * ?")
    fun everyMinute() {
        performRecalculation(RecalculationPeriod.EVERY_MINUTE)
    }

    fun performRecalculation(recalculationPeriod: RecalculationPeriod) {
        scheduledTriggerExecutors
                .filter { it.recalculationPeriod == recalculationPeriod }
                .forEach { it.executeTrigger() }
    }
}

@Component
class ProjectFormTriggerExecutor : ScheduledTriggerExecutor() {
    override val entityClass = ProjectForm::class
}

@Component
class ProjectTriggerExecutor : ScheduledTriggerExecutor() {
    override val entityClass = Project::class
}

@Component
class DistrictTriggerExecutor : ScheduledTriggerExecutor() {
    override val entityClass = District::class
}

@Component
class AreaMonitoringFragmentTriggerExecutor : ScheduledTriggerExecutor() {
    override val entityClass = AreaMonitoringFragment::class
}
```

Comment: Is it Spring Boot app? Have you forgotten to add `@EnableScheduling`?

Comment: I had that on, its the lazy initialization as Czar commented

Comment: How will the Spring DI Container create TriggerScheduler? You have a parameter  `val scheduledTriggerExecutors: List<ScheduledTriggerExecutor>` and I don't know how the DI is going to resolve that?
You will need to remove @Component from TriggerScheduler and have an @Bean method in a @Configuration class to create this. Then it should behave as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe global lazy bean initialization is turned on somewhere. To quickly test if it is, try annotating `TriggerScheduler` with `@Lazy(false)`. You can also look for `spring.main.lazy-initialization=true` property somewhere in Spring Environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the issue, a teammate had set spring.main.lazy-initialization=true.

Comment: Glad I could help :)